# How do I get vba to add all (and only) cells across a row that are formatted in a currency (£ for specificity)?

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry that I don't even have any basic code to show for this problem, as I have no idea where to start.

I'm just trying to tidy up a spreadsheet that otherwise looks like `=sum(AA+AD+AG...ad nauseum)`. I figure there's a better way to do this.

I have multiple cells in each row that contain numbers that I want to add, but only the ones that are formatted as £'s.

It should also be able to move down the column and work across.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `=CELL("format",A1)` to find what you want, C2 vs G for currency and general.  So a helper column and a simple SUMIF means no need for VBA

In VBA you can use `left(range("a1").Text,1)`

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for the advice. I have already tried this and then followed it up with something like =sumif(A1:BH1, "C0-") but this doesn't work. I keep getting 0. Do you have any suggestions for this? I just thought using vba may be a better option...

Comment: i added my data in A, then in column B filled down, I added =cell("format",a1) then in C I did `=SUM(($A$1:$A$5)*--($B$1:$B$5="C2"))` or `=SUMIF(B1:B5,"C2",A1:A5)`

Comment: Ah, I see. I've tried that and it works, but I'd like to be able to do it without needing the helper column. Do you have any suggestions? Is there anything inherent in the formatting of a currency cell/value that I may be able to use to differentiate from others?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UDF¹.

```
Function subtotalCurrency(rng As Range, _
                 Optional smbl As String = "£")
    Dim txt As String, ttl As Double, c As Range
    For Each c In rng
        If CBool(InStr(1, c.Text, smbl, vbBinaryCompare)) Then
            txt = Trim(Replace(c.Text, smbl, vbNullString))
            If IsNumeric(txt) Then
                subtotalCurrency = subtotalCurrency + CDbl(txt)
            End If
        End If
        Debug.Print c.Text
    Next c
End Function
```

[image: gbp_sumif]

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>